# select statement inside an inner join, not showing select fields

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

I have two tables that I want to perform an inner join on. Both tables share a field, the ID so I want to perform the join on that. The result I want to get is one table that shows the Name, school and major (from table 1) and Address, Email and phone from (from table 2). 
Table1 :
Name, school, Major, ID, Teacher

Table2:
Address, Phone, ID, Email

**Here's my query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       Name,
       school,
       Major
  FROM Table1
 INNER
  JOIN(SELECT Address,
              Phone,
              Email
         FROM Table 2) Table2
    ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
 WHERE .....
```

The problem is that when I run the query, it pulls the correct amount of results, but does not show the Address, Email and Phone fields I want to pull from table 2. Am I misunderstanding something about joins?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to specify the columns from the other table in your outer `SELECT` clause. Here's a simplier version without any subquery:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        t1.Name,
        t1.School,
        t1.Major,
        t2.Address,
        t2.Phone,
        t2.Email
FROM    Table1 AS t1
        INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2
            ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

where `t1` and `t2` are called `ALIAS`.

Answer (score 0):

Inner query should act like a table but you have given its alias name same as original table. So it is comparing the condition id's from original table and giving you correct count. Secondly you have not mentioned I'd column in inner query and you have not selected the columns of table2 in main select query.